# System or catalog tables - DBA_ / DBC - outputs are volatile

Tags: oracle11g, teradata

I am trying to get list of all tables/views (in other words all objects) where a particular field is referenced using the system or catalog tables. I am using the following query.

```
select * 
  from dba_col_comments 
 where column_name like('SXX_AXXX_%') 
 order by 1;
```

However, the output is volatile. When I repeatedly run the same query without any changes the output is varies. For instance, it produced 9300 records and then 9350 after a couple of minutes and then 9347 after a couple of minutes.

I am observing the same behaviour in Teradata as well.

My theory would be - in a production enironment temporary objects that are created are probably getting an entry in the system/catalog tables.

Any thoughts/directions?

Comment: Your theory sounds fairly good, it may well be Oracle creating the objects for it's own internal processes. You haven't described what your problem is with this though... What _exactly_ are you after and are you sure you're after [comments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4009.htm#SQLRF01109)? Why don't you exclude the system schemas?

Answer (score 0):

In Teradata you will find that as `global temporary tables` are instantiated (referenced by an SQL statement) records should be added to the data dictionary table TVM. These records are then dropped after the session logs off leaving just the base table record associated with the original `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` statement that was submitted.

You can find these instances using the view `DBC.AllTempTables`.

In Teradata, `volatile tables` are not maintained within the data dictionary.

**EDIT - Your mileage may vary but this should get you started on Teradata**

```
SELECT D1.DatabaseNameI AS DatabaseName_
     , T1.TVMNameI AS TableName_
     , F1.FieldName AS ColumnName_
  FROM "DBC".TVM T1
 INNER JOIN
       "DBC".Dbase D1
    ON D1.DatabaseId = T1.DatabaseId
 INNER JOIN
       "DBC".TVFields F1
    ON F1.DatabaseId = T1.DatabaseId
   AND F1.TableId = T1.TVMId
WHERE F1.FieldName = 'MyColumn'
  --AND D1.DatabaseNameI IN ('{Database1}', ... '{Database99}') -- Filter on databases
  AND F1.FieldType in ('i', 'i1', 'i2', 'i8') -- Integer, ByteInt, SmallInt, BigInt
  --AND T1.TableKind IN ('T') -- Optional Filter to just tables.
  AND NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 'x'
        FROM "DBC".TempTables TT1
       WHERE Tt1.TableId = T1.TVMId
     )
;
```

Comment: what I am trying - In one of our projects we are trying to change the datatype of surrogate key from integer to decimal(18,0). This is a very important field is used in close to 14000 tables. I am trying to ensure using the system / catalog / data dictionary tables is a fool proof way of finding the database objects where these are present. However, like I mentioned I am trying to see why this volatility in the output and how I can eliminate them. In other words how can I get list of database objects where this field is present or referenced and to ensure those objects are not temporary.

Comment: You should be able to restrict the databases considered to just those containing your target and staging tables. Eliminate any database where an end user has the ability to create a table. Any base definition for a global temporary table that references this column should also be considered for modification.

Comment: Thanks @Rob - your replies were really useful and helpful.